# After making and executing the code below, it does not show up in my terminal for vscode (in C)

Tags: c, if-statement, cs50

New to coding...
When i make and run the code below, the output does not show up in my terminal window. I don't know what i'm doing wrong? (I am trying to create a pyramid but i can't see the pyramid in the terminal on Vscode after running the code)

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
       //prompt user for input
    int n;
    while (true)
    {
        n = get_int("Height: ");
        if(n > 0 && n < 9)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    //for height of pyrammid
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        // for dashes/spaces to shift pyramid right.
        for(int l = j; l < 8; l++)
        {
            //print space to shift pyramid right.
            printf(" ");
        }
        // for length of pyramid
        for (int k = j; k >= n; k--)
        {
            //print a brick
            printf("#");
        }
    //move to new line
    printf("\n");
    }
}
```

---

Comment: `for (int k = j; k >= n; k--)`  Will this for loop ever enter. I believe `j` is never larger than or equal to `n` so your code should never execute `printf("#");`

Comment: More generally, if the expected behavior of the guts of a conditional loop never seem to transpire (in this case, a `printf("#")`), *always* consider the possibility that the condition for continuation is false on inception (as it is in this case).

Comment: @drescherjm ty.